# add css with express and node js

Tags: css, node.js, express

Please help me as i am trying to add a css file all the day long and always fail 
app.js code :

```
    var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.set('views', '../node_modules/express/views/');




app.use(express.static('public'));



app.get("/",function(req,res){


     console.log("welcome");
    res.render("test");

});



app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("connected")   
});
```

test.ejs code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
    <!--    <link type="text/css" href="app.css">-->
<!--    <link href="/public/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/html">-->
<!--    <link  type="text/css" href="/public/app.css">-->
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/app.css" >-->

<link rel="Style" type="text/css" href="/app.css" >
</head>
<body>
    <h1>here</h1>

</body>
```

css code :

```
body{
    background-color: green;
}
```

server structure :
root-->public-->app.css

i also faced the error : was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff). but i solved it and and tried a lot of ways to change the path and keep it in the same folder with the ejs
thank you in advance

Comment: `rel="stylesheet"` is correct. For the rest, sounds like you need to set up routes for static files.

Comment: @HereticMonkey with my respect i used the app.use(express.static('public')); method to create route for static files and i just trying to connect 1 css so no need to subfiles. also i didn't get your answer rel="stylesheet" is correct as i had tried a lot of formatting for the css link check the test.ejs file you will find a lot of comments from my previous tries and i copied it with the code to make it easier to guess what i already had tried . Thank for your help anyway

Comment: Commented code doesn't exist as far as I'm concerned, because it's not running. What you need is `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/app.css" type="text/css" />`.

Comment: your solution lead to my older problem was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff). and thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In app.js:

```js
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

In ejs/html:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/index.css">
```

[Serving static files in Express](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Answer (score 0):

in your app.js

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys thank you all but the solution was just to add ../ before public

```
app.use(express.static('../public'));
```

as express was searching for public inside the server folder that has the app.js